# Sequelize - How to search range in multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js, sql-update, nodes

Mysql Query :

> SELECT
> * FROM
> advisor_product_range WHERE 5 BETWEEN from_range AND to_range;

How to replicate the same in sequelize format

```
    const AdvisorProductRangeDataGdp = await AdvisorProductRange.findAll({
        attributes: ['office_id','yyyymmdd','product_type','from_range','to_range','amount_per_order'],
        where: {
            from_range: {
                    [dbOp.gte]: gdpCount
                },
            to_range: {
                    [dbOp.lte]: gdpCount
                }
        }
    });
```

OUTPUT OF THIS QUERY IN MYSQL TERMS :

```
> SELECT `office_id`, `yyyymmdd`, `product_type`, `from_range`,
> `to_range`, `amount_per_order` FROM `advisor_product_range` AS
> `AdvisorProductRange` WHERE `AdvisorProductRange`.`from_range` <= 5 AND
> `AdvisorProductRange`.`to_range` >= 5;
```

Mysql Table Structure :
[image: mysql table]

**Version** : **sequelize** :5.8

Comment: And what's wrong with the generated SQL? Basically it's the same as `between`. Try to get the SQL execution plan and look if `between` is converted to two conditions with `>=` and `<=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Issue was found out its was related to the operator used in the query
  was switch in the incorrect way .

```
const AdvisorProductRangeDataGdp = await AdvisorProductRange.findAll({
        attributes: ['office_id','yyyymmdd','product_type','from_range','to_range','amount_per_order'],
        where: {
            from_range: {
                    [dbOp.lte]: gdpCount
                },
            to_range: {
                    [dbOp.gte]: gdpCount
                }
        }
    });
```